# Filtro de Informações da Combobox Dinâmica

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Gostaria de saber como fazer um filtro dinâmico de dados, para aparecer somente os dados relacionados com o selecionado, por exemplo:
Tenho no meu banco a tabela `Empregado` e `Empresa`, como exemplo eu tenho:

- Funcionario 1(fk_empresa 1), Trabalha na Empresa 1;
- Funcionario 2(fk_empresa 1), Trabalha na Empresa 1;
- Funcionario 3(fk_empresa 2), Trabalha na Empresa 2;
- Funcionario 4(fk_empresa 2), Trabalha na Empresa 2;

Então quando eu clicasse no Combobox, e seleciona-se a empresa 1 eu queria que somente aparecesse os funcionários 1 e 2, no combobox debaixo. Mas agora gostaria de saber como fazer, provavelmente deve ser em AJAX, mas AJAX eu não sei muito por isso peço ajuda a vocês.
**Código das Comboboxes:

Empresa:**

```
<div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name"> **Empresa** </div>  
        <div class="profile-info-value">
            <select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <option value="" selected disabled="disabled" hidden>Selecione a Empresa</option>
        <?php $line = $searchSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($line as $thread):?>
             <option value="<?php echo $thread['cod_empresa']; ?>"><?php echo $thread['razao_social']; ?></option> <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Empregado:**

```
<div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name"> Nome do Empregado </div>
        <div class="profile-info-value">
        <select name="empregado" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <option value="" selected disabled="disabled" hidden>Selecione o Empregado</option>
        <?php 
        $plataform = $requestSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($plataform as $contour): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $contour['cod_empregado']; ?>"><?php echo $contour['nome']; ?></option> <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
De acordo com sugestões eu refiz algumas partes, e apesar do ID da empresa ser pego(comprovado por alert), ele não está retornando nada, porque? Segue o arquivo para visualização
Arquivo filterEmp:

```
<?php
    require 'conexao.php';
    $pdo = conectar();

    if (isset($_POST['id_empresa'])) :
        try{    
        $cod_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_empregado WHERE fk_empresa = ?";  
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $SQL );
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $cod_empresa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        extract($row);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        'ERROR :' . $e->getMessage()."<br>";
        'ERROR :' . $e->getCode();
    }endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar ajax mesmo.

Usando jquery ficaria assim:

1. Crie um script que retorne somente os funcionários filtrados por empresa, como no `Empregados` que você colocou no exemplo.
2. Use a função [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) do jquery, quando o valor do campo `empresa_destino` for alterado:

```js
$("select[name=empresa_destino]").change(function() {
  var id_empresa = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'empregados.php',
    'data': {'id_empresa': id_empresa},
    'method': 'POST',
    'success': function(returnHtml) {
      $(".resultado").html(returnHtml);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name"> **Empresa** </div>  
        <div class="profile-info-value">
            <select name="empresa_destino" id="form-field-1" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <option value="" selected disabled="disabled" hidden>Selecione a Empresa</option>
            <option value="1"> Empresa 1</option>
            <option value="2"> Empresa 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Olá @Vanildo fiz as mudanças mas quando há a mudança nada ocorre, exatamente como seria o meu arquivo em PHP para consulta

Comment: Atualizei o post

Comment: Eu esqueci de acrescentar o method na requisição ajax. Veja como está agora, e se funciona

Comment: Ainda assim não aconteceu nada

Comment: No arquivo de consulta você deve retornar o HTML inteiro, com o as divs e select já prontos.

Comment: Eu fiz essa postagem a um tempo no meu blog, mais ou menos o que você quer fazer: http://blog.toneladas.com.br/respondendo-no-stackoverflow-1.html

Comment: Ok agora entendi vou tentar desenvolver algo aqui e depois mostro uma resposta